# Nginx module for serving files from MongoDB's Make error

Tags: c, mongodb, nginx

I am trying to run nginx-gridfs from github to connect mongodb with nginx .
I followed the exact procedure as shown in the https://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs README file .when i configured using the statement below

```
./configure --add-module=/home/yogesh/nginx-gridfs-master --prefix=/usr/local/nginx




Configuration summary
  + using system PCRE library
  + OpenSSL library is not used
  + md5: using system crypto library
  + sha1: using system crypto library
  + using system zlib library

  nginx path prefix: "/usr/local/nginx"
  nginx binary file: "/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx"
  nginx configuration prefix: "/usr/local/nginx/conf"
  nginx configuration file: "/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf"
  nginx pid file: "/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid"
  nginx error log file: "/usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log"
  nginx http access log file: "/usr/local/nginx/logs/access.log"
  nginx http client request body temporary files: "client_body_temp"
  nginx http proxy temporary files: "proxy_temp"
  nginx http fastcgi temporary files: "fastcgi_temp"
  nginx http uwsgi temporary files: "uwsgi_temp"
  nginx http scgi temporary files: "scgi_temp
```

Now when I press MAKE to make the file I get the following error

```
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror -g  --std=c99 -Isrc -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs -I src/http -I src/http/modules \
        -o objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_keepalive_module.o \
        src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_keepalive_module.c
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/home/yogesh/nginx-gridfs-master/mongo-c-driver/src/*.h', needed by `objs/addon/nginx-gridfs-master/ngx_http_gridfs_module.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/yogesh/nginx-1.2.6'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

What should I do to resolve the error .....

Comment: Check to see what is in the path `/home/yogesh/nginx-gridfs-master/mongo-c-driver/src/`.  Are there `.h` files?

Comment: I don't think that module has been supported for the last 2 years and it's compatibility with MongoDB ran out in like v1.6. However that moans about the c driver for mongodb: https://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs/pull/48

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx-gridfs has submodule(mongo-c-driver).

You may try to restart from ./configure after executing following command in nginx-gridfs directory.

```
git submodule update --init
```

Comment: Yes it expects the mongodb C driver to be in a subdirectory of grid-fs as the error says.